# Suggestions for regex to parse MIDI note names?

Tags: objective-c, regex, midi

I'm trying to design a regular expression to extract MIDI note names and octaves from a string, to eventually turn the result into an actual MIDI note value.

MIDI note names are a discrete range from C-2 to G8, corresponding to 0...127, so that:

```
0 = C-2
1 = C#-2
2 = D-2
...
125 = F8
126 = F#8
127 = G8
```

Here's what I have now:

`^([CDEFGAB]#?)(-?[0-8])`

This expression matches all the valid MIDI notes with capture groups, and discards obvious ones like `K9`. The problem is that it also matches bogus input like `A10`, and gives me note = A octave = 1, which is wrong.

**EDIT**: Of course this also accepts wrong octaves like -8, but I can filter them after the match.

This is part of a project in Objective-C, which uses the [ICU regex](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) flavor.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^([CDEFGAB]#?)((?:-[1-2])|[0-8])$`

This will fix several problems. First, since we add the $ at the end of the regex, it will stop at the end of the string (this prevents A10, as we match precisely one digit). Then, the segment

`((?:-[1-2])|[0-8])`

will either take a negative value between 1 and 2 (and not capture it twice, from `(?:...)`), or it will take the original range of positive 0-8.

Comment: Oops. Fixed that in one but not the other. Fixing now. Nice catch!